# Using @Inject Instance to get EJB and CDI beans that implements specific interface

Tags: java, ejb, cdi

In our application we have CDI (@ApplicationScoped annotation) and EJB (@Stateless annotaion) beans that structured like this:

```
MyInterface
    MyAbstractClass
       MyBean (CDI or EJB)
```

I'm using below to get all the beans (CDI and EJB) in my application that implements **MyInterface**:

```
@Inject
Instance<MyIterface> beans;
```

Here I see two weird things:

- I'm getting only CDI beans and not EJB beans.
- When creating EJB bean that implements directly the **MyInterface** interface, without extending **MyAbstractClass**, than in this case this bean getting injected by the inject above.

How can I get all the beans, CDI and EJB, with the inject above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from section 4.9.2.1 of EJB 3.2 specification:

> ```
> @Stateless
> public class A implements Foo { ... }
>
> @Stateless
> public class B extends A implements Bar { ... }
> ```
>
> Assuming Foo and Bar are local business interfaces and there is no associated deployment descriptor, session bean A exposes local business interface Foo and session bean B exposes local business interface Bar, but not Foo.
>
> Session bean B would need to explicitly include Foo in its set of exposed views for that interface to
>   apply. For example:
>
> ```
> @Stateless
> public class A implements Foo { ... }
>
> @Stateless
> public class B extends A implements Foo, Bar { ... }
> ```

---

In your example, `MyBean` defined as EJB does not expose `MyInterface`, and, as a result, is not injected at `Instance<MyInterface>`.

There are two ways to handle it:

- declare EJBs as implementing `MyInterface`;
- annotate EJBs with `@Local(MyInterface.class)`

Warning for the approach with `@Local` - this EJB will satisfy only those injection points which use one of the interfaces provided as a parameter to the annotation. You won't be able to inject it at

```
@Inject
MyBean bean;
```

Also, you won't be able to cast the injected proxy to any other type.